# Powershell script with params *and* functions

Tags: powershell, parameters

I want to write a powershell script that takes in params and uses functions.

I tried this:

```
param
(
  $arg
)

Func $arg;


function Func($arg)
{
  Write-Output $arg;
}
```

but I got this:

```
The term 'Func' is not recognized as the name 
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At func.ps1:6 char:5
+ Func <<<<  $arg;
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Func:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Fine, I thought. I'll try this instead:

```
function Func($arg)
{
  Write-Output $arg;
}


param
(
  $arg
)

Func $arg;
```

But then, I got this:

```
The term 'param' is not recognized as the name 
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\akina\Documents\Work\ADDC\func.ps1:7 char:10
+     param <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (param:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Is what I'm asking for doable? Or am I being unreasonable in my request?

Comment: The order of a powershell script is typically, 1) Params, 2) Functions 3) Function calls/ordered cmdlets to execute.

Comment: Christopher Ranney, that's a helpful summarisation. If you had posted this as a question, I would have voted it up.

Comment: You can vote up comments if your heart so desires. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The param block in a script has to be the first non-comment code.  After that, you need to define the function before you invoke it e.g.:

```
param
(
  $arg
)

function Func($arg)
{
  $arg
}

Func $arg
```

The Write-Output is unnecessary in your example since the default behavior is to output objects to the output stream.

Comment: And what if we move that function definition into a Module and import that on our machine, then call that as @Tola Odejayi is trying to do?

Comment: @FarrukhWaheed The same applies to a module. Though it isn't probably the typical case, a PSM1 can define parameters and execute code (not just define fucnctions) just like a regular script file.

Answer (score 4):

All you need ius to make sure PARAM is first string of your script.

Answer (score -3):

You can put the param tag inside the function..

Something like this:

```
function func($avg)
{
    param
    (
         $avg
    )
}
```